# Streaming NumPy data as input to Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I was reading https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets to look for a solution to stream NumPy arrays stored in npz files, which may be too large to fit in memory. This snippet is provided in the documentation:

```
# Load the training data into two NumPy arrays, for example using `np.load()`.
with np.load("/var/data/training_data.npy") as data:
  features = data["features"]
  labels = data["labels"]

# Assume that each row of `features` corresponds to the same row as `labels`.
assert features.shape[0] == labels.shape[0]

features_placeholder = tf.placeholder(features.dtype, features.shape)
labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(labels.dtype, labels.shape)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features_placeholder, labels_placeholder))
# [Other transformations on `dataset`...]
dataset = ...
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={features_placeholder: features,
                                          labels_placeholder: labels})
```

Does this method really allow you to stream NumPy data? Doesn't `features = data["features"]` load the data entirely into memory?

Answer (score 1):

The utilities for `.npy` files indeed allocate the whole array into memory.

If all of your input data fit in memory, the simplest way to create a Dataset from them is to convert them to `tf.Tensor` objects and use `Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` like you are doing above.

In the case that the file doesn't fit into memory, it seems like the only recommended approach is to first convert the `npy` data into a `TFRecord` format, and then use the `TFRecord` data set format, which can be streamed without fully loading into memory.

Below is the example:

**Convert to TFRecords:**

```
def array_to_tfrecords(X, y, output_file):
  feature = {
    'X': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=X.flatten())),
    'y': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=y.flatten()))
  }
  example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
  serialized = example.SerializeToString()

  writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_file)
  writer.write(serialized)
  writer.close()
```

**Read TFRecordDataset:**

```
def parse_proto(example_proto):
  features = {
    'X': tf.FixedLenFeature((345,), tf.float32),
    'y': tf.FixedLenFeature((5,), tf.float32),
  }
  parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
  return parsed_features['X'], parsed_features['y']

def read_tfrecords(file_names=("file1.tfrecord", "file2.tfrecord", "file3.tfrecord"),
                   buffer_size=10000,
                   batch_size=100):
  dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(file_names)
  dataset = dataset.map(parse_proto)
  dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size)
  dataset = dataset.repeat()
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
  return tf.contrib.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types, dataset.output_shapes)
```